# Upload an image from Android to Amazon S3?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need to upload a bitmap to Amazon S3. I have never used S3, and the docs are proving less than helpful as I can't see anything to cover this specific requirement. Unfortunately I'm struggling to find time on this project to spend a whole day learning how it all hangs together so hoping one of you kind people can give me some pointers.

Can you point to me to a source of reference that explains how to push a file to S3, and get a URL reference in return?

More specifically:
- Where do the credentials go when using the S3 Android SDK?
- Do I need to create a bucket before uploading a file, or can they exist outside buckets?
- Which SDK method do I use to push a bitmap up to S3? 
- Am I right in thinking I need the CORE and S3 libs to do what I need, and no others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Amazon S3 API documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/) to get a feel for what can and can't be done with Amazon S3. Note that there are two APIs, a simpler REST API and a more-involved SOAP API.

You can write your own code to make HTTP requests to interact with the REST API, or use a SOAP library to consume the SOAP API. All of the Amazon services have these standard API endpoints (REST, SOAP) and in theory you can write a client in any programming language!

Fortunately for Android developers, Amazon have released [a (Beta) SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) that does all of this work for you. There's a [Getting Started](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4225549089557252) guide and [Javadocs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/) too. With this SDK you should be able to integrate S3 with your application in a matter of hours.

The Getting Started guide comes with a full sample and shows how to supply the required credentials.

Conceptually, Amazon S3 stores data in **Buckets** where a bucket contains **Objects**. Generally you'll use one bucket per application, and add as many objects as you like. S3 doesn't support or have any concept of folders, but you can put slashes (/) in your object names.

Comment: Thanks David. I've spent some time with the getting started guide and the docs and samples but so far it's been a slow process to get to a point of seeing suitable sample code. Amazon seem to have written the docs for people who are going to learn everything and spend a lot of time with it - I don't have that luxury, I just want to shove a file in, and do other stuff. Looks like I need to put a lot more time in which is a shame.

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm going on three days now trying to find an easy to understand example for uploading images securely to s3.

Comment: To be honest I think they should improve the documentation!

Answer (score 14):

```
String      ACCESS_KEY="****************",
            SECRET_KEY="****************",
            MY_BUCKET="bucket_name",
            OBJECT_KEY="unique_id";              
  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
                AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
                java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
                s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
                s3.setEndpoint("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/");
                List<Bucket> buckets=s3.listBuckets();
                for(Bucket bucket:buckets){
                    Log.e("Bucket ","Name "+bucket.getName()+" Owner "+bucket.getOwner()+ " Date " + bucket.getCreationDate());
                }
                Log.e("Size ", "" + s3.listBuckets().size());
                TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
                UPLOADING_IMAGE=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Screenshot.png");
                TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(MY_BUCKET,OBJECT_KEY,UPLOADING_IMAGE);
                observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                        // do something
                        progress.hide();
                        path.setText("ID "+id+"\nState "+state.name()+"\nImage ID "+OBJECT_KEY);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                        int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                        progress.setProgress(percentage);
                        //Display percentage transfered to user
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                        // do something
                        Log.e("Error  ",""+ex );
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Thanks for this great example, the likes of which I couldn't find in the docs. In fact, I only needed the first couple of lines, how to set the credentials and the region.

Comment: @Andan: Above is working fine.Do you know how to return Bitmap after images downloaded using `TransferUtility.download()` method? The below doesn't work.   `protected Bitmap processBitmap(String d){
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/" + d);
transferObserver = transferUtility.download(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, d, file );
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(transferObserver.getAbsoluteFilePath(), options);
return bm;
} `

Answer (score 3):

We can directly use "Amazone s3" bucket for storing any type of file on server, and we did not need to send any of file to Api server it will reduce the request time.

**Gradle File :-**

```
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
```

**Manifest File :-**

```
<service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

**FileUploader Function in any Class :-**

```
 private void setUPAmazon() {
 //we Need Identity Pool ID  like :- "us-east-1:f224****************8"
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getActivity(),
                "us-east-1:f224****************8", Regions.US_EAST_1);
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        final TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getActivity());
        final File file = new File(mCameraUri.getPath());
        final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(GeneralValues.AMAZON_BUCKET, file.getName(), file, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("onStateChanged", id + state.name());
                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    String url = "https://"+GeneralValues.AMAZON_BUCKET+".s3.amazonaws.com/" + observer.getKey();
                    Log.e("URL :,", url);
//we just need to share this File url with Api service request.  
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below mentioned class to Upload data to amazon s3 buckets.

```
public class UploadAmazonS3{

private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;
private AmazonS3Client s3Client = null;
private TransferUtility transferUtility = null;
private static UploadAmazonS3 uploadAmazonS3;

/**
 * Creating single tone object by defining private.
 * <P>
 *     At the time of creating
 * </P>*/
private UploadAmazonS3(Context context, String canito_pool_id)
{
    /**
     * Creating the object of the getCredentialProvider object. */
    credentialsProvider=getCredentialProvider(context,canito_pool_id);
    /**
     * Creating the object  of the s3Client */
    s3Client=getS3Client(context,credentialsProvider);

    /**
     * Creating the object of the TransferUtility of the Amazone.*/
    transferUtility=getTransferUtility(context,s3Client);

}

public static UploadAmazonS3 getInstance(Context context, String canito_pool_id)
{
    if(uploadAmazonS3 ==null)
    {
        uploadAmazonS3 =new UploadAmazonS3(context,canito_pool_id);
        return uploadAmazonS3;
    }else
    {
        return uploadAmazonS3;
    }

}

/**
 * <h3>Upload_data</h3>
 * <P>
 *     Method is use to upload data in the amazone server.
 *
 * </P>*/

public void uploadData(final String bukkate_name, final File file, final Upload_CallBack callBack)
{
    Utility.printLog("in amazon upload class uploadData "+file.getName());

    if(transferUtility!=null&&file!=null)
    {
        TransferObserver observer=transferUtility.upload(bukkate_name,file.getName(),file);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state)
            {
                if(state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED))
                {
                    callBack.sucess(com.tarha_taxi.R.string.AMAZON_END_POINT_LINK+bukkate_name+"/"+file.getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal)
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex)
            {
                callBack.error(id+":"+ex.toString());

            }
        });
    }else
    {
        callBack.error("Amamzones3 is not intialize or File is empty !");
    }
}

/**
 * This method is used to get the CredentialProvider and we provide only context as a parameter.
 * @param context Here, we are getting the context from calling Activity.*/
private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentialProvider(Context context,String pool_id)
{
    if (credentialsProvider == null)
    {
        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                pool_id, // Identity Pool ID
                AMAZON_REGION // Region
        );
    }
    return credentialsProvider;
}

/**
 * This method is used to get the AmazonS3 Client
 * and we provide only context as a parameter.
 * and from here we are calling getCredentialProvider() function.
 * @param context Here, we are getting the context from calling Activity.*/
private AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context,CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider)
{
    if (s3Client == null)
    {
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider);
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(AMAZON_REGION));
        s3Client.setEndpoint(context.getString(com.tarha_taxi.R.string.AMAZON_END_POINT_LINK));
    }
    return s3Client;
}

/**
 * This method is used to get the Transfer Utility
 * and we provide only context as a parameter.
 * and from here we are, calling getS3Client() function.
 * @param context Here, we are getting the context from calling Activity.*/
private TransferUtility getTransferUtility(Context context,AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client)
{
    if (transferUtility == null)
    {
        transferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonS3Client,context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return transferUtility;
}

/**
 * Interface for the sucess callback fro the Amazon uploading .
 * */
public interface Upload_CallBack
{
    /**
     *Method for sucess .
     * @param sucess it is true on sucess and false for falure.*/
    void sucess(String sucess);
    /**
     * Method for falure.
     * @param errormsg contains the error message.*/
    void error(String errormsg);

}
```

}

use the below method to access the above calss :

```
 private void uploadToAmazon() {
    dialogL.show();
    UploadAmazonS3 amazonS3 = UploadAmazonS3.getInstance(getActivity(), getString(R.string.AMAZON_POOL_ID));
    amazonS3.uploadData(getString(R.string.BUCKET_NAME), Utility.renameFile(VariableConstants.TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME, phone.getText().toString().substring(1) + ".jpg"), new UploadAmazonS3.Upload_CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void sucess(String sucess) {
            if (Utility.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                dialogL.dismiss();
                /**
                 * to set the image into image view and
                 * add the write the image in the file
                 */
                activity.user_image.setTag(setTarget(progress_bar));
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(getString(R.string.AMAZON_IMAGE_LINK) + phone.getText().toString().substring(1) + ".jpg").
                        networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into((Target) activity.user_image.getTag());

                Utility.printLog("amazon upload success ");
                new BackgroundForUpdateProfile().execute();
            } else {
                dialogL.dismiss();
                Utility.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.network_connection_fail));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String errormsg) {
            dialogL.dismiss();
            Utility.showToast(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.network_connection_fail));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called S3UploadService. First you would need to convert your Bitmap to a File. To do so take a look at this post:

[Convert Bitmap to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file)

S3UploadService is a library that handles uploads to Amazon S3. It provides a service called S3UploadService with a static method where you provide a Context (so the static method can start the service), a File, a boolean indicating if said file should be deleted after upload completion and optionally you can set a callback (Not like an ordinary callback though. The way this works is explained in the README file).

It's an IntentService so the upload will run even if the user kills the app while uploading (because its lifecycle is not attached to the app's lifecycle).

To use this library you just have to declare the service in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...>

    ...

    <service
        android:name="com.onecode.s3.service.S3UploadService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Then you build an S3BucketData instance and make a call to S3UploadService.upload():

```
    S3Credentials s3Credentials = new S3Credentials(accessKey, secretKey, sessionToken);
    S3BucketData s3BucketData = new S3BucketData.Builder()
            .setCredentials(s3Credentials)
            .setBucket(bucket)
            .setKey(key)
            .setRegion(region)
            .build();

    S3UploadService.upload(getActivity(), s3BucketData, file, null);
```

To add this library you need to add the JitPack repo to your root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and then add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.OneCodeLabs:S3UploadService:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

Here is a link to the repo:
https://github.com/OneCodeLabs/S3UploadService

This answer is a bit late, but I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

you can upload image and download image in s3 amazon. you make a simple class use this WebserviceAmazon

```
public class WebserviceAmazon extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String mParams;
private String mResult = "x";
WebServiceInterface<String, String> mInterface;
private int mRequestType;
private  String UserId;
private Context mContext;


public WebserviceAmazon(Context context,String imagePath,String AppId,int type) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mParams = imagePath;
    this.mRequestType = type;
    this.UserId = AppId;
}

public void result(WebServiceInterface<String, String> myInterface) {
    this.mInterface = myInterface;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String ACCESS_KEY ="abc..";
    String SECRET_KEY = "klm...";

    try {
        if (mRequestType == 1) { // POST
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "imageName", new File(mParams));
            s3Client.putObject(request);

            mResult = "success";
        } if (mRequestType == 2) { // For get image data
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
            S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketName", mParams));
            S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(objectContent);

           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);



            mResult = "success";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mResult = e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPostExecute(result);
    mInterface.success(this.mResult);

}

public interface WebServiceInterface<E, R> {
    public void success(E reslut);

    public void error(R Error);
}

}
```

call this webservice any where in project

```
    WebserviceAmazon amazon = new WebserviceAmazon(getActivity(), imageName, "", 2);
    amazon.result(new WebserviceAmazon.WebServiceInterface<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String reslut) {

        }

        @Override
        public void error(String Error) {

        }
    });

    return totalPoints;
}
```

Comment: Dose this code work with video? can i just switch out the file path with a video?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code to upload image to **Amazon AWS S3 bucket**
Hope this is helpful for you
First let me clear some key points
you can either take image from camera or pick image from gallery ,AWS store images as a file so first thing you need to store image to local dir and get path of image then create a file from that path after this you will be able to upload that imagefile to AWS.

first you need to add configration on **Oncreate**

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(KEY,SECRET);
         s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

private void uploadFile() {

        verifyStoragePermissions(CustomCameraActivity.this);

        TransferUtility transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(getApplicationContext())
                        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .s3Client(s3)
                        .build();

        TransferObserver uploadObserver= null;
        
        File file2 = FileUtils.getFile(CustomCameraActivity.this, storageImagePath);//here i am converting path to file ,,FileUtils.getFile is custom class
        
            uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload("your bucket name", imageNameWithoutExtension + ".jpg", file2);// imagenamewithoutExtension is actually the name that you want to store 

        uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uploadResourcesApi(uploadResoucesURL);
                    //imageFile.delete();
                    //file2.delete();
                } else if (TransferState.FAILED == state) {
                    //imageFile.delete();
                    //file2.delete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                float percentDonef = ((float) bytesCurrent / (float) bytesTotal) * 100;
                int percentDone = (int) percentDonef;

                //tvFileName.setText("ID:" + id + "|bytesCurrent: " + bytesCurrent + "|bytesTotal: " + bytesTotal + "|" + percentDone + "%");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
    }
```

this is fileUtils class

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * @version 2009-07-03
 * @author Peli
 * @version 2013-12-11
 * @author paulburke (ipaulpro)
 */
public class FileUtils {
    private FileUtils() {} //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

    /** TAG for log messages. */
    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging

    public static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

    public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";

    /**
     * Gets the extension of a file name, like ".png" or ".jpg".
     *
     * @param uri
     * @return Extension including the dot("."); "" if there is no extension;
     *         null if uri was null.
     */
    public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
     */
    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if Uri is a MediaStore Uri.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaUri(Uri uri) {
        return "media".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Convert File into Uri.
     *
     * @param file
     * @return uri
     */
    public static Uri getUri(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path only (without file name).
     *
     * @param file
     * @return
     */
    public static File getPathWithoutFilename(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // no file to be split off. Return everything
                return file;
            } else {
                String filename = file.getName();
                String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                // Construct path without file name.
                String pathwithoutname = filepath.substring(0,
                        filepath.length() - filename.length());
                if (pathwithoutname.endsWith("/")) {
                    pathwithoutname = pathwithoutname.substring(0, pathwithoutname.length() - 1);
                }
                return new File(pathwithoutname);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the given file.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(File file) {

        String extension = getExtension(file.getName());

        if (extension.length() > 0)
            return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1));

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the give Uri.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(getPath(context, uri));
        return getMimeType(file);
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is {@link LocalStorageProvider}.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return LocalStorageProvider.AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    
    public static String getReadableFileSize(int size) {
        final int BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES = 1024;
        final DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        final String KILOBYTES = " KB";
        final String MEGABYTES = " MB";
        final String GIGABYTES = " GB";
        float fileSize = 0;
        String suffix = KILOBYTES;

        if (size > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
            fileSize = size / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
            if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                    fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                    suffix = GIGABYTES;
                } else {
                    suffix = MEGABYTES;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(dec.format(fileSize) + suffix);
    }

    
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, File file) {
        return getThumbnail(context, getUri(file), getMimeType(file));
    }

    
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) {
        return getThumbnail(context, uri, getMimeType(context, uri));
    }

    
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri, String mimeType) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to get thumbnail");

        if (!isMediaUri(uri)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "You can only retrieve thumbnails for images and videos.");
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (uri != null) {
            final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got thumb ID: " + id);

                    if (mimeType.contains("video")) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    }
                    else if (mimeType.contains(FileUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE)) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.e(TAG, "getThumbnail", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return bm;
    }

    
    public static Comparator<File> sComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            // Sort alphabetically by lower case, which is much cleaner
            return f1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(
                    f2.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    };

   
    public static FileFilter sFileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return files only (not directories) and skip hidden files
            return file.isFile() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    
    public static FileFilter sDirFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return directories only and skip hidden directories
            return file.isDirectory() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    
    public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // The MIME data type filter
        intent.setType("*/*");
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

then you will also need this class

```
public class LocalStorageProvider extends DocumentsProvider {

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents";

    private final static String[] DEFAULT_ROOT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Root.COLUMN_ROOT_ID,
            Root.COLUMN_FLAGS, Root.COLUMN_TITLE, Root.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, Root.COLUMN_ICON,
            Root.COLUMN_AVAILABLE_BYTES
    };
    
    private final static String[] DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
            Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, Document.COLUMN_FLAGS, Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
            Document.COLUMN_SIZE,
            Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED
    };

    @Override
    public Cursor queryRoots(final String[] projection) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        final MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ? projection
                : DEFAULT_ROOT_PROJECTION);
        
        File homeDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = result.newRow();
        // These columns are required
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_ROOT_ID, homeDir.getAbsolutePath());
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, homeDir.getAbsolutePath());
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_TITLE, "Internal storage");
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_FLAGS, Root.FLAG_LOCAL_ONLY | Root.FLAG_SUPPORTS_CREATE);
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        // These columns are optional
        row.add(Root.COLUMN_AVAILABLE_BYTES, homeDir.getFreeSpace());
        // Root.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE is another optional column and useful if you
        
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String createDocument(final String parentDocumentId, final String mimeType,
                                 final String displayName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File newFile = new File(parentDocumentId, displayName);
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LocalStorageProvider.class.getSimpleName(), "Error creating new file " + newFile);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openDocumentThumbnail(final String documentId, final Point sizeHint,
                                                     final CancellationSignal signal) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(documentId, options);
        final int targetHeight = 2 * sizeHint.y;
        final int targetWidth = 2 * sizeHint.x;
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > targetHeight || width > targetWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;
           
            while ((halfHeight / options.inSampleSize) > targetHeight
                    || (halfWidth / options.inSampleSize) > targetWidth) {
                options.inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(documentId, options);
        // Write out the thumbnail to a temporary file
        File tempFile = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile("thumbnail", null, getContext().getCacheDir());
            out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LocalStorageProvider.class.getSimpleName(), "Error writing thumbnail", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (out != null)
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LocalStorageProvider.class.getSimpleName(), "Error closing thumbnail", e);
                }
        }
        // It appears the Storage Framework UI caches these results quite
        // aggressively so there is little reason to
        // write your own caching layer beyond what you need to return a single
        // AssetFileDescriptor
        return new AssetFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(tempFile,
                ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY), 0,
                AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor queryChildDocuments(final String parentDocumentId, final String[] projection,
                                      final String sortOrder) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Create a cursor with either the requested fields, or the default
        // projection if "projection" is null.
        final MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ? projection
                : DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION);
        final File parent = new File(parentDocumentId);
        for (File file : parent.listFiles()) {
            // Don't show hidden files/folders
            if (!file.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                // Adds the file's display name, MIME type, size, and so on.
                includeFile(result, file);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor queryDocument(final String documentId, final String[] projection)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Create a cursor with either the requested fields, or the default
        // projection if "projection" is null.
        final MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(projection != null ? projection
                : DEFAULT_DOCUMENT_PROJECTION);
        includeFile(result, new File(documentId));
        return result;
    }

    private void includeFile(final MatrixCursor result, final File file)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = result.newRow();
        // These columns are required
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, file.getAbsolutePath());
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName());
        String mimeType = getDocumentType(file.getAbsolutePath());
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        int flags = file.canWrite() ? Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_DELETE | Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE
                : 0;
        // We only show thumbnails for image files - expect a call to
        // openDocumentThumbnail for each file that has
        // this flag set
        if (mimeType.startsWith("image/"))
            flags |= Document.FLAG_SUPPORTS_THUMBNAIL;
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_FLAGS, flags);
        // COLUMN_SIZE is required, but can be null
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_SIZE, file.length());
        // These columns are optional
        row.add(Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, file.lastModified());
        // Document.COLUMN_ICON can be a resource id identifying a custom icon.
        // The system provides default icons
        // based on mime type
        // Document.COLUMN_SUMMARY is optional additional information about the
        // file
    }

    @Override
    public String getDocumentType(final String documentId) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(documentId);
        if (file.isDirectory())
            return Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR;
        // From FileProvider.getType(Uri)
        final int lastDot = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastDot >= 0) {
            final String extension = file.getName().substring(lastDot + 1);
            final String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            if (mime != null) {
                return mime;
            }
        }
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDocument(final String documentId) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new File(documentId).delete();
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openDocument(final String documentId, final String mode,
                                             final CancellationSignal signal) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(documentId);
        final boolean isWrite = (mode.indexOf('w') != -1);
        if (isWrite) {
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        } else {
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }
}
```