# Converting/Saving bitmap image as file in Android app

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ftp

I want to FTP an image from my Android app to my server. The problem is, I am trying to do this right now:

`String data = client.storeFile("picture.png", myBitmap);`

but you can't send bitmaps through storeFile, only files. So my question is: how can I put this bitmap into a file to send? Do I have to save the picture on the phone first? (I would prefer not to). Any ideas? Thanks.

```
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        Bitmap myBitmap = my bitmap;

        try {
            client.connect("myhost");
            boolean login = client.login("un", "pw");
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            String data = client.storeFile("picture.png", myBitmap);
            //here is where I need a file, not bitmap

            logout = client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780289/2694468). You can change the **context.getCacheDir()** to the path that you want to store the bitmap file in the device.  Is it what you're looking for? there's a file is created from a bitmap. To retreive the File entity, just use

```
File myFile = new File(filename);
```

Comment: I actually figured out that .storeFile takes in an `InputStream` not a `File` so that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out that .storeFile takes in an InputStream, not a file. So what I had to do to send my bitmap was this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,
        0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        bitmapdata);

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
boolean result2 = client.storeFile("serverpath", bs);
```