# How to load a existent bitmap into Picasso

Tags: java, android

The reason that I'm using Picasso is because I need a rounded image and I could achieve this with Picasso using `Transformation`:

```
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

And then :

```
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.image)
            .transform(new CircleTransform()).into(photo);
```

But I'm taking a Bitmap from a Camera and I need to put the image inside of `ImageView`, rounded! I was trying to use [Bitmap to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file) but it doesnt' work!

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView or similar libraries?