# Array of Bitmaps into Video with ffmpeg

Tags: android, arrays, video, ffmpeg, bitmap

I'm Facing current porblem.
I have an Array of 100 Bitmaps. these are Screenshots i took from a view.
I used JCodec to make it to a video, buts its waay to slow. Im hoping to get better results with FFmpeg

Now i want to use the FFmpeg Library. Simillar questions were asked but i have no Idea how to use ffmpeg and how i have to use it in my specific case. All i see are weird Complex Commands See:

```
 File dir = your directory where image stores;
    String filePrefix = "picture"; //imagename prefix
    String fileExtn = ".jpg";//image extention
    filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
    File src = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);// image name should ne picture001, picture002,picture003 soon  ffmpeg takes as input valid
```

> complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", src + "", "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "aac", "-vf", "setpts=2*PTS", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-crf", "10", "-r", "15", "-shortest", "-y", "/storage/emulated/0/" + app_name + "/Video/" + app_name + "_Video" + number + ".mp4"};

The Problem is, that in this case he is using a Path. I need it to be from an Array. And i have no idea what to do with the String (ComplexCommands) :/
My Bitmaps are like this:

Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmaps[100];

this is filled later on.

if anyone is searching on how to do it with JCodec:

```
 try {
                    out = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/***yourpath***/output"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");
                    // for Android use: AndroidSequenceEncoder

                    AndroidSequenceEncoder encoder = new AndroidSequenceEncoder(out, Rational.R(25, 1));
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
                        // Generate the image, for Android use Bitmap

                        // Encode the image
                        System.out.println("LOO2P"+i);
                        encoder.encodeImage(bitmaps[i]);
                    }
                    // Finalize the encoding, i.e. clear the buffers, write the header, etc.
                    encoder.finish();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("fNF");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOE");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("IOSSE");
                    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [the ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow), the way you described is exactly how it is intended to be done. To implement this you should write each image from your array into a single file according to the described naming conventions. I don't know if this will help with your performance issues though.
Writing the images to files can be done following [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780289/10928836)

```
for (int i = 0; i<bitmapArray.length(); i++){
    // Write to file while incrementing the file name
    writeToFile(bitmapArray[i], i);
}
```

As far as I could find, ffmpeg does not support directly encoding from an array.