# How to convert bitmap to file

Tags: android, kotlin

I must upload image file by use retrofit
this is Api

```kotlin
@POST("/image")
    suspend fun uploadImage(
        @Body request: UploadImageRequest,
    ): Response<UploadImageResponse>
```

UploadImageRequest

```kotlin
data class UploadImageRequest(
    @SerializedName("image") val image: String,
)
```

I implement get image in device storage
this is code that get image

```kotlin
private val imageResult = registerForActivityResult(
        StartActivityForResult(),
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val imageUri = result.data?.data
            imageUri?.let {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                    bitmap =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, imageUri)
                } else {
                    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, imageUri)
                    bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                }
            }
            binding.imageActivityChangeUserInformationUserProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
```

I don't know how I can upload that image
I tried that image to string by use base64 encode
but encoding string is too long

I tried create temp image file in device storage.
But, changed policy, scoped storage?
I couldn't make a new file
my app sdk is 33

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780289/12153321

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file and you want to upload that file then do not first make a bitmap out if it.

Certainly not if you then ask to save that bitmap to file as then you can start over again.

And pdf's and doc's let them convert to bitmap pretty bad.

So just upload the file.

Just the bytes of the file.