# Cannot upload image to amazon s3 using http put

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing an Android app, where users can create posts with images. Images are uploading to Amazon S3. So how every user can upload an image, I dont use Amazon AWS SDK, because its methods need secret key. I try to upload an image  using HTTP put request. I send first request to backend, and it sends to me signature and other paramrters which is use to upload an image. Unfortunately the second response from amazon contains error.

Here is the first request and response:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 53
Host: wrum-wrum.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

file_name=1439474973659_crp.jpg&file_type=image%2Fjpg


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 14:09:46 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AY0SlTYzkavxu34-pcuMIEGDPuRSDlKuM.%2FTRySP3UVyIIatnqLSGE8%2Bx%2BP239TL9rjPQxjVRbzD8; Path=/; HttpOnly

11b
{"signed_request":"https://babadoo.s3.amazonaws.com/1439474973659_crp.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJMXM46BCWD5WDGTQ&Content-Type=image%2Fjpg&Expires=1439475046&Signature=ZsqF%2BaCCeZmTTPkiTWLG5Ckix1U%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read","url":"https://babadoo.s3.amazonaws.com/1439474973659_crp.jpg"}
0
```

Here is the second request and response:

```
PUT /1439474973659_crp.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJMXM46BCWD5WDGTQ&Content-Type=image%2Fjpg&Expires=1439475046&Signature=ZsqF%2BaCCeZmTTPkiTWLG5Ckix1U%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVALIABLE (java 1.4)
Content-Length: 1242599
Host: babadoo.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: 36D4D3E461AF0850
x-amz-id-2:     +/LpGcZD6ZMdbZDq31Zt5ablP5CZIbBElaD1pm6of7MrndAwXe6ortO3uJNVgn8sGQ03o2waie0=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 14:10:00 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3

357
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJMXM46BCWD5WDGTQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT

image/jpeg
1439475046
x-amz-acl:public-read
/babadoo/1439474973659_crp.jpg</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>ZsqF+aCCeZmTTPkiTWLG5Ckix1U=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 0a 31 34 33 39 34 37 35 30 34 36 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 62 61 62 61 64 6f 6f 2f 31 34 33 39 34 37 34 39 37 33 36 35 39 5f 63 72 70 2e 6a 70 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>36D4D3E461AF0850</RequestId><HostId>+/LpGcZD6ZMdbZDq31Zt5ablP5CZIbBElaD1pm6of7MrndAwXe6ortO3uJNVgn8sGQ03o2waie0=</HostId></Error>
0
```

Code:

```
public String uploadPhoto(final File file) {


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadURL);

            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            String result = null;

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file_name", file.getName()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file_type", "image/jpg"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                int i = 1;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            if (result != null) {
                int putURLpos = result.indexOf(parseStringFragment);
                if (putURLpos != -1) {
                    putURL = result.substring(putURLpos + parseStringFragment.length(),
                            result.indexOf("\"", putURLpos + parseStringFragment.length()));

                    try {

                        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                        trustStore.load(null, null);

                        SSLSocketFactory sf = (new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore));
                        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                        BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
                        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpParams, true);

                        SchemeRegistry sr = new SchemeRegistry();
                        sr.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                        sr.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
                        ThreadSafeClientConnManager ccManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, sr);

                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccManager, httpParams);

                        URI uri = new URI(putURL);
                        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(uri);
                        put.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                        put.setHeader("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVALIABLE (java 1.4)");

                        EntityBuilder eb = EntityBuilder.create();
                        eb.setFile(file);
                        put.setEntity(eb.build());
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);


                        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                        String res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                        int i = 1;
                        i++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return uploadedPhotoURL;
}
```

Comment: might help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7310289/794088

Comment: Please include the request(s) and response(s) as part of your question (and not as links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find the solution. It was my fault, I sent

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file_type", "image/jpg"));
```

for the first request, and

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

in the second request.